# iOS mail inbox does not show addresses

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

I use a catch all email address on my domain, and would like to be able to figure out what address is being sent spam email.  Unfortunately, I can't find a way to see what address an email in my inbox was sent to. Is there a way to determine the addressee of an email in iOS 8?

Comment: Inbound email shows the "To:" field on my phone, perhaps you only have one email account configured?

Comment: ah, I see now in other emails there is a to field, must be something in particular about this spam that prevents mail from being able to read it from the headers.

Comment: That likely means there is no "To:" header, instead your domain was likely used in a "BCC:".  Additionally BCC's never appear in the headers after the email is received, the mail server may however generate an "X-Apparently To:" header that will be visible if you can see all headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would likely have to have an email app capable of displaying the raw headers of the email to trace this information. I do not believe the iOS 8 Mail app has this capability; it simply displays the most user-friendly information (your catch-all To: address). However, if you can access the same account through the Mac OS X Mail application (or Outlook, etc.), you can view the raw headers there.